# Laravel 9 404 Error on GET Request updating database when clicking button

Tags: laravel, get, sql-update, http-status-code-404, laravel-9

I was having another laravel question here. I was facing 404 error when clicking the button
**Confirm Registration** on the purpose of changing its database based on the item id on the view. Logically, I think my code should have work on this part.

```
<a href="{{ route('registration.confirm', $view->uniquecode) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm Registration</a>
```

However, it comes up 404 Error. Herby I include all the related code in the section.

**Error**

[image]

**Frontend** (To prove that the data passing is successful in the view)
[image]

**web.php**

```
Route::controller(ResidenceController::class)->group(function(){
    Route::get('/residence/register', 'registration')->name('residence.register');
    Route::get('/residence/search', 'SearchProperty')->name('residence.search');
    Route::get('/registration/confirmation/{$uniquecode}', 'ConfirmRegistration')->name('registration.confirm');
});
```

The focus is on:

> Route::get('/registration/confirmation/{$uniquecode}',
> 'ConfirmRegistration')->name('registration.confirm');

**Controller**

```
 public function ConfirmRegistration($uniquecode){
    
            $confirm = Properties::where('uniquecode', $uniquecode)->update(['status'=>'pending', 'tenant_id'=>Auth::user()->id]);
    
            if($confirm){
                session()->flash('alert-success','Successfully Applied');
            }
            else{
                session()->flash('alert-warning','Error Occured');
            }
        }
```

**register.blade.php**

```
  @foreach ($toSearch as $key=>$view)
                <div class="card" style="width: 50rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <img src="{{ (!empty($tenant->unit_image))? url('uploads/properties/'.$tenant->unit_image):url('uploads/properties/default.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid" alt="unit image" >
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 20%">Property</td>
                                        <td style="width:10%; text-align: center">:</td>
                                        <td>{{$view->name}}</td>
                                    </tr>
    
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Address</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">:</td>
                                        <td>{{$view->address1}},{{$view->address2}},{{$view->city}}</td>
                                    </tr>
    
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Landlord</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">:</td>
                                        <td>{{$view->landlord->name}}</td>
                                    </tr>
    
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Contact No</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">:</td>
                                        <td>{{$view->landlord->phone_number}}</td>
                                    </tr>
    
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Status</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">:</td>
                                        <td>{{$view->status}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                </div>
            <br>
    
                <!--To confirm registration-->
                @if( $view->status != 'approved')
                    <a href="{{ route('registration.confirm', $view->uniquecode) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm Registration</a>
                @endif
    
            </div>
    @endforeach
```

The focus is on:

> @if( $view->status != 'approved')
> uniquecode) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm
> Registration
> @endif

Database:
[image]

Comment: route parameters don't have `$` in them, they are not PHP variables ... `/registration/confirmation/{uniquecode}`

Comment: I literally suck. Thanks for the info. It works now. Problem solved!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `post` method for inserting data (register),

anyway, change your route parameter `$uniquecode` to `uniquecode`.

and when you use `route` second argument is a compact, use

```
route('registration.confirm',['uniquecode' => $view->uniquecode]);
```